# How do I update Ubuntu version 11.10?

Tags: 11.10

I was recently gifted a computer and it has Ubuntu 11.10 and I was wondering how I update it? And how do I factory reset it once it updates?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 tells you it's the 2011-October release (ie. a *year.month* format is used for releases), it *release-upgraded* to the next release which is the 12.04 (or 2012-April release). Both are now years past their EOL or *end-of-life*, so your *upgrade* path is now gone.  I would re-install a supported release of Ubuntu, or more likely a supported *flavor* of Ubuntu (*flavors* are lighter, which makes them perform better on older hardware).  What machine do you have?

Comment: The following link I'd usually provide for EOL (*end-of-life*) releases https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades, however in your case I suspect you've no data installed of value, so I'd install a supported system. Details of hardware are required to know what your system will support (my box is a 2009 dell, so it'll run anything, but 11.10 is an unusual system to install on anything after late 2012, so I'm wondering if there was a reason why it was used).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) - I would not recommend keeping anything from this installation except for a back up of your personal files. I would not even keep `/home`. A LOT has changed since 2011

Comment: just reinstall 20.04 on it if you don't need any data

Comment: As noted by @guiverc in the comments above you can alter the sources.list files in /etc/apt to the "old-releases" addresses and update one at a time (you can jump from one LTS to the next, but 11.10 is probably not an LTS).

One thing to note is that it's likely you have a 32bit variant installed, and if the machine you are using does not have a 64bit processor the highest level you could upgrade to through official channels will be 18.04 (which is an LTS anyway so it should still be relatively fine). Note that there are other distributions which continue to support 32bit.